# What is this C++ map doing?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

I have a global variable, "testGrid" which I am attempting to create a map to, so that I can reference it with a string.  The map seems like it works in that I can assign values to the grid, but it is not assigning them to "testGrid" as I intend it to.

Is the map creating a new grid, separate from the global variable?  How can I get the map to reference the grid correctly?  In this code, the output from the two tests should be identical.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct signalGrid{
    double signal[20][200];
    signalGrid();
};


void mapTest(std::map<string,signalGrid> &temp_map);
map<string,signalGrid> signalIndex;
signalGrid testGrid;


int main(){
    int i;
    mapTest(signalIndex);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        signalIndex["T1"].signal[i][0]=5;}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST="<<testGrid.signal[i][0]<<"\n";}
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"TEST2="<<signalIndex["T1"].signal[i][0]<<"\n";}
    return 0;   
}


void mapTest(std::map<string, signalGrid> &temp_map){

    temp_map["T1"]=testGrid; 
    return; 
}

signalGrid::signalGrid(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<200;j++){
            signal[i][j]=0;}}
}
```

Comment: @pmr Not exactly, unfortunately. :( They still have the same misunderstanding, but it's a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are copying `testGrid` into the value corresponding to key `"T1"`. Doing anything with that value will only modify the copy.

You could have a `map<string, reference_wrapper<signalGrid>>`, but I'm not exactly sure why you want the global `testGrid` variable in the first place. Why not get rid of `testGrid` and just deal with `signalIndex["T1"]`?

Comment: OK, that is probably what I will do.  I thought that the map was creating a pointer to the variable, testGrid, not creating its own grid that I could reference later.

Comment: @user1042343 Pretty much everything in C++ is "by value" unless you ask otherwise. The only exceptions are types that *represent* reference semantics, such as `reference_wrapper` or the smart pointers.